# Using Facebook Graph API Pages Search

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am playing with Facebook Graph API. I am interested in getting results like pages search.

I can look for places like this:

```
search?q=audi&type=place
```

and I get json with data I want, like website, location etc.
Example:

```
{{
    ""datadata": ": [[
        {{
            "category": "Automotive Parts Store",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "139492049448901",
          "name": "Automotive Parts Store"
        }
      ],
      "location": {
        "city": "Belgrade",
        "country": "Serbia",
        "latitude": 44.8206,
        "longitude": 20.4622,
        "zip": "11000"
      },
```

But when I want to search pages and get public page data in json with a request like this:

```
search?q=audi&type=page
```

this is json I get:

```
    {
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

**What's happening here, why can't I do the search and is there a way to achieve this? 
I am reading Facebook API documentation for two days now and I can't find anything relevant.**

Python code that I am using (token removed)

```
import facebook
token = "////////"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version = 2.7)
events = graph.request("/search?type=page&q=cafe&fields=about,fan_count,website")

print(events)
```

Comment: what type of access token did you use?

Comment: intially i used user token, after that i created app token and i got info that i have to get approval from facebook for that action

> To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be > reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content > Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable> features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pages/search` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the api end point, use with valid access token:

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/pages/search?q=m&fields=id,is_eligible_for_branded_content,is_unclaimed,link,location,name,verification_status